# How to fix 'Incompatible Types' error with Vaadin Flow CallBackDataProvider

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vaadin-flow, vaadin10, jakarta-ee

I tried making a callbackdataprovider with vaadin flow for my grid. But it returns an incompatible types error when i tried making it.

I've already minimized the code to the simplest problem version of the problem and it still doesnt work, and i followed the vaading flow guide for making one, and its pretty much the same as my code :

```
dataProvider = DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
            query -> {  
                List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();                
                return people;              
            },          
            query -> {          
                int i = 0;              
                return i;               
            });
```

this should work, but instead i get the following error :

> incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,F exist so
>   that com.vaadin.data.provider.CallbackDataProvider conforms to
>   com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.CallbackDataProvider

Comment: What's the complete variable declaration?

Comment: it was CallBackDataProvider dataprovider but i used the code below, and appareantly DataProvider works, so its solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Vaadin 10+ (Flow) related classes are in the `com.vaadin.flow` package. Please use `DataProvider` from that package. [Here](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-and-components-documentation/blob/0b3a4354a192aecdeaf490d4c52641c9c6417ed7/documentation/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/tutorial/databinding/DataProviders.java#L288) is a code example:

```
import com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.*;

DataProvider<Person, Void> dataProvider = DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
            // First callback fetches items based on a query
            query -> {
                ...
                return persons.stream();
            },
            // Second callback fetches the number of items for a query
            query -> getPersonService().getPersonCount());
```

Comment: yeh i was using the right package but appareantly used the wrong class in the declaration, CallBackDataProvider doesnt work, but DataProvider did, appreciate the help

Comment: Alright, you can mark this post as answer then (check mark on the left).